# What is the meaning of "with little to no side effects" in the sentences?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "with little to no side effects" in the following sentences, (Source: What Is Quercetin? Benefits, Foods, Dosage, and Side Effects  Written by Ryan Raman)

> Quercetin is found in many fruits and vegetables and is safe to
>   consume. As a supplement, it appears to be generally safe ***with
>   little to no side effects***. In some instances, taking more than
>   1,000 mg of quercetin per day may cause mild symptoms like headaches,
>   stomach aches, or tingling sensations

Does "it appears to be generally safe with little to no side effects" mean "Quercetin appears to be generally safe with little side effects, or quercetin appears to be generally safe with no side effects" ?

Does "safe with little to no side effects" mean "safe with little side effects, or safe with no side effects" ?

Does "to" in "safe with little ***to*** no side effects" mean "or" ?

Comment: It's safe, and has either few side effects or none at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I means "either there are little side effects, or there are no side effects"  In this context "little" doesn't mean "small" but it means "few".

The word "to" indicates a range, for example "That tree is 5 to 7 metres tall" (it is between 5 and 7)  So "little to no" means "between a zero and a small number". We use it when we are uncertain of the exact number, but we know it is small and it could be zero.

> Many shops have little to no toilet paper left.

We don't know for sure if the drug has side effects, but we are sure that there are only a few and there might be none at all.